# Changed value of element in form isn't posted

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dom, post

I have a form with one input element which gets its value from the last page by post,
like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost/maps_en2/next-page" method="POST">
    <input name="srchZoom" type="hidden" value="<?php if( isset($_POST['srchZoom']) ) echo $_POST['srchZoom']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" class="buttonForLink" value="next page"/> | 
</form>
```

This form is designed and serves as a link.

I need to be able to change the value of the element, after a mapIdle event, and then when the link is hit, to post the new value to the next page.

So I do it like this:

```
function mapIdle(){
    document.getElementsByName("srchZoom").innerHTML = map.getZoom();
}
```

I chechked and indeed after the mapIdle event the value of the element is changed.
I checked it with clicking a button that triggers this:

```
alert(document.getElementsByName("srchZoom").innerHTML);
```

The problem is that when hitting the link the form posts the original value of the element instead of the one set by the function `mapIdle()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using "value" instead of "innerHTML":

```
function mapIdle(){
    document.getElementsByName("srchZoom").value = map.getZoom();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. Same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementsByName("srchZoom")
```

returns array (getElements - plural). So, with document.getElementsByName("srchZoom").innerHTML you added property innerHTML to that array. You should change it to

```
document.getElementsByName("srchZoom")[0].value = map.getZoom();
```

to change the value of first element with name *srchZoom*.